# Not getting exact reason of crash in apple crash reporting. What is the best way for Crash Logging in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

What is the best way to log crashes in iOS?
App Store rejected binary when I integrated firebase crashlatycs. Apple crash report works fine in TestFlight. But in production I am not getting exact reason of crash. Any Idea guys?